# Using templates how can I calculate the average of x numbers?

Tags: c++, math, statistics

So I have statistics.h with this

```
template<typename T>
class OwnType {
public:
    OwnType() {};
    virtual ~OwnType() {};

    void nextValue(T value) {
        nmbrCnt++;
        cout << "Value: " << value << endl;
        cout << "# of Values so far: " << nmbrCnt << endl;
        average = (average + value) / nmbrCnt; // calculate average <----- WRONG!

        variance += pow(value - average, 2) / nmbrCnt; // calculate standard variance/deviation
    };

    T getAverage() { return average; }
    T getVariance() { return variance; }
    T getRange() { return max - min; }

private:
    T max = NULL;
    T min = NULL;
    T average = NULL;
    double variance = 0;
    int nmbrCnt = 0;
    bool firstCall = true;
};
```

And in main.cpp I do this:

```
void main() {
    OwnType<double> list;

    list.nextValue(10.5);
        cout << "Average: " << list.getAverage() << endl;
    list.nextValue(5);
        cout << "Average: " << list.getAverage() << endl;
    list.nextValue(3);
        cout << "Average: " << list.getAverage() << endl;
    list.nextValue(24.6)
        cout << "Average: " << list.getAverage() << endl;
    }
```

However, there seems to be a logic error or I'm not understanding templates right. I can calculate the average just fine, if it's in an array, but without an array, without any storage whatsoever, I'm stumped. Any iedas?

Comment: What's the specific problem? The templates look ok, although I don't like the assignment to `NULL`, and the type for the variance seems arbitrary. Do you need help calculating the running mean and standard deviation?

Comment: Nothing to do with template, it is just your formula which is wrong, it should be `average = ((nmbrCnt - 1) * average + value) / nmbrCnt;`

Comment: Note that if `T` is an integral type, then the formulas will be evaluated in integer arithmetic. Do you want the truncation effects? In fact, why use templates at all?

Comment: Yea, thanks. I meant the formula. My bad. I think it's time for a break from C++ for a couple of days. Why use templates? Because I want, and because I need to understand how they work. I'm self studying C++.

Comment: Consider storing your running average and variance as a long double, even if T is a float or integral type.  Otherwise, see what happens when you take the average of one, one billion, minus one billion when T is float.  This will also prevent integer truncation.

Comment: Considered and implemented, you were right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formulas for the running mean and variance are incorrect.

Some code from my Monte Carlo library which will help you:

```
 // Running variance calculation requires the previous value of the
 // mean so we do this one first.
 variance = path > 1 ? 
            (path - 1.0) / path * (variance + (mean - pv) * (mean - pv) / path) : 
             0.0;
 mean = ((path - 1.0) * mean + pv) / path;
```

Here, `pv` is the new value to be added and `path` the number of values in the distribution once the new value is incorporated.

If `T` is an integral type then be careful with truncation effects with integer division. Your running mean and variance will deteriorate due to the truncation.

Better still, ditch the templates altogether and use `double`.